# substring using slice and a dataframe series as an end

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice, series

I have a dataframe as such:

> Blockquote

```
df  
Out[458]:

    strings
0  lui sau chun  
1  d1420152  
2  98764879333  
3  minglee    
4  g1927384  
5  hannah
```

What I would like to do is to extract 2/3rd's of the string for each value in the strings column. As you can see, the length of each string is different and the so the 2/3rds position to slice off would also be different. My target output would look like this:

> Blockquote

```
df
Out[459]:
   strings          substring
0  lui sau chun     liu sau
1  d1420152         d1420   
2  98764879333      98764879
3  minglee          ming
4  g1927384         g1927
5  annah            hann
```

I tried:

```
x=(df['strings'].str.len()*2/3).apply(np.floor).astype(int)
df['strings'].str.slice(0,x)
```

but this just gave me the following output:

> Blockquote

```
Out[451]: 
0   NaN
1   NaN
2   NaN
3   NaN
4   NaN
Name: strings, dtype: float64
```

can anyone help?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Better is use [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) with count `len`s and select by indexing by `[]`:

```
print (df['strings'].apply(lambda x: x[:int(len(x)*2/3)]))
0    lui sau 
1       d1420
2     9876487
3        ming
4       g1927
5        hann
Name: strings, dtype: object
```

---

Another solution:

First create new column and then `apply` with `axis=1` for process by rows:

```
df['l'] =(df['strings'].str.len()*2/3).apply(np.floor).astype(int)
print (df)
        strings  l
0  lui sau chun  8
1      d1420152  5
2   98764879333  7
3       minglee  4
4      g1927384  5
5        hannah  4

print (df.apply(lambda x: x['strings'][0: x['l']], axis=1))
0    lui sau 
1       d1420
2     9876487
3        ming
4       g1927
5        hann
dtype: object
```